# Error in Weyl character formula computation.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, maple, quaternions

I need someone with a keen eye for errors. I am trying to use the Weyl character formula for the symplectic group Sp$(4,\mathbb{C})$ on certain matrices coming from 2x2 quaternion matrices. Summing these traces in my case should give an integer output (since they are supposed to represent dimensions of spaces of modular forms)...however I am not getting integers.

In particular I have a quaternion algebra (which for now is just Hamiltons quaternions) and a maximal order. The units of this maximal order (which form the list A) are being used to create 2x2 diagonal and anti diagonal matrices, forming a group G. In order to apply Weyl's character formula I am using a homomorphism into Sp($4,\mathbb{C}$) to get 4x4 complex symplectic matrices. The commands quat1, quat2, quat3, quat4 and Mat do this below (the maths is correct, we do actually get a symplectic matrix so there is nothing to worry about on that side of things). The set Gamma1 below is the 4x4 version of G lying inside Sp($4,\mathbb{C}$).

In order to use the Weyl character formula I must plug two non-conjugate eigenvalues from each element of Gamma1 into a certain rational function which I define by the use of P and Weyl. This part of the program is correct since I used it in a previous sheet for other dimension calculations.

I then get the dimension by summing these values and dividing by the number of elements in Gamma1. However I am getting rational number outputs when I should be getting integers. Can anyone see the errors?

**MY CODE:**

```
with(LinearAlgebra):

with(linalg):

quat1:= proc(a::list); a[1] + a[2]*I; end proc:

quat2:= proc(a::list); a[1] - a[2]*I; end proc:

quat3:= proc(a::list); a[3] + a[4]*I; end proc:

quat4:= proc(a::list); -a[3] + a[4]*I; end proc:

Mat:=proc(a::list,b::list,c::list,d::list); Matrix([[quat1(a), quat1(b), quat3(a), quat3(b)],[quat1(c), quat1(d), quat3(c), quat3(d)],[quat4(a), quat4(b), quat2(a), quat2(b)],[quat4(c), quat4(d), quat2(c), quat2(d)]]); end proc:

A:=[[1,0,0,0],[-1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,-1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,-1,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,-1], [1/2,1/2,1/2,1/2],[1/2,1/2,1/2,-1/2],[1/2,1/2,-1/2,1/2],[1/2,1/2,-1/2,-1/2],[1/2,-1/2,1/2,1/2],[1/2,-1/2,1/2,-1/2],[1/2,-1/2,-1/2,1/2],[1/2,-1/2,-1/2,-1/2],[-1/2,1/2,1/2,1/2],[-1/2,1/2,1/2,-1/2], [-1/2,1/2,-1/2,1/2],[-1/2,1/2,-1/2,-1/2],[-1/2,-1/2,1/2,1/2],[-1/2,-1/2,1/2,-1/2],[-1/2,-1/2,-1/2,1/2],[-1/2,-1/2,-1/2,-1/2]]:

Gamma1:= [seq(seq(Mat(A[i],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],A[j]),i=1..24),j=1..24), seq(seq(Mat([0,0,0,0],A[i],A[j],[0,0,0,0]),i=1..24),j=1..24)]:

EV:=[seq(Eigenvalues(Gamma1[i]), i=1..1152)]:

Q1:= proc(i); if (conjugate(EV[i][1]) - EV[i][3] = 0) then EV[i][4] else EV[i][3] end if; end proc:

Q2:= proc(i); if (conjugate(EV[i][1]) - EV[i][2] = 0) then Q1(i) else EV[i][2] end if; end proc:

Weyl:= proc(m::integer,n::integer); simplify((a^(2*m+2*n+4)*b^(m+2*n+3) - a^(2*m+2*n+4)*b^(m+1) - b^(m+2*n+3) + b^(m+1) - a^(m+2*n+3)*b^(2*m+2*n+4) + a^(m+1)*b^(2*m+2*n+4) + a^(m+2*n+3) - a^(m+1))/((a^2-1)*(b^2-1)*(a*b-1)*(a-b))); end proc:

P:=proc(x,y,m,n); subs(a=x,b=y,b=y,Weyl(m,n)/(a^(m+n)*b^(m+n))); end proc:

dim:= proc(m::integer,n::integer); simplify(expand(sum(P(EV[j][1], Q2(j),m,n),j=1..1152)))/1152; end proc:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you really want Maple to try symbolic summation (ie. get a formula in terms on symbolic summation index endpoints, and only after that instantiate at the finite numeric endpoints 1..1152)?

Or would you want to use `add` instead of `sum` inside procedure `P`? Note that `add` has special evaluation rules and so will not try to compute Q2(j) for symbolic (not yet an integer) `j`. For finite summation, there can be difficulties with premature evaluation of function calls like Q2(j) inside a `sum` call. Hence for literal finite summation you might be safer with `add`. I haven't tested whether that a problem for your code.

Inside procedure Weyl, as marked up here, there are subexpression such as `((a^2-1)(b^2-1)(a*b-1)*(a-b))` where there are no multiplication signs between some of the bracketed terms. Without explicit `*` symbols between the touching backets that will get parsed as function application rather than as multiplication, for 1D input. (As 2D Math input it could have either * to denote multiplication explicitly or a space to denote multiplication implicitly. I suspect that your code is 1D text. The explicit * covers both forms, and is thus most prudent.)

Comment: Wow thanks, changing to add did the trick! I don't really know much about programming and didn't know the add command existed. Why did the sum commnd not work then?

Comment: The missing multiplication sign must have been some kind of typo, it appeared in my maple sheet.